# How do I open another app programmatically in Android?

Tags: java, android

What I want to do is simple, but I don't know if it's possible. I want my app to open a specific area of another app. This specific area of the other app is a form; my app contains information to complete this form. I want my app to open this form with the information in the editable text boxes. Does anyone know if that is possible?

The other app I'm trying to open is a bitcoin client open source.

Code: https://github.com/schildbach/bitcoin-wallet/
Google Play: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.schildbach.wallet

If you open this app (the bitcoin client) and click on "Send Bitcoins", the form I'm trying to open will appear. There are 3 editable text boxes there and I have the information to fill then in my app.

That's it guys, hope someone knows.

PS: I successfully opened the app using:

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("de.schildbach.wallet");
startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

But I didn't opened the form, so it was useless.

Comment: Could `de.schildbach.wallet.ui.send.SendCoinsActivity` see [Mainfest file](https://github.com/schildbach/bitcoin-wallet/blob/master/wallet/AndroidManifest.xml) be the activity you're trying to start?

Comment: Unfortunatelly, the app closes if I do: Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("de.schildbach.wallet");
                 startActivity(LaunchIntent);

Comment: You don't want the launch activity. Construct a Intent that passes one of the intent-filters of `de.schildbach.wallet.ui.send.SendCoinsActivity` (there are 4 in the manifest). I guess the simplest way would be using a intent with a uri that can be used as parameter of the constructor of [com.google.bitcoin.uri.BitcoinURI](https://bitcoinj.github.io/javadoc/0.11/com/google/bitcoin/uri/BitcoinURI.html#BitcoinURI%28java.lang.String%29).